Command not found for connecting bluetooth device
I've been attempting to connect my bluetooth device (simple earbuds) to my laptop but each attempt is a miserable failure. I checked my settings and I only receive a message which reads "no bluetooth device connected", but does not give me the option to either

turn bluetooth on or
pair a device

I'm using a KDE launcher, plasma. I've used the following commands:
~]$ gatttool
bash: gatttool: command not found
~]$ hcitool
bash: hcitool: command not found
~]$ hcitool lescan
bash: hcitool: command not found
~]$ sudo hcitool lescan
sudo: hcitool: command not found
~]$ hcitool lecc
bash: hcitool: command not found

I've used the other recommended Commands like bluetoothctl or bluez and received the same result. I'm using Linux and the Konsole terminal.
Can anyone help me solve the problem?

hello, can you add the output of lspci -kv the textpart with bluetooth, or if it is a network bluetooth combo , also the network card, perhaps you need a specific driver.

the package name for hcitool is bluez. I dont know your package manager

Firstly, when asking a question, it is important to include the operating system that you are using. The error that you are receiving show that the commands aren't found. What have you done to find out what needs to be done to acquire them? Add that information to the question. Do not post it in the comments.

If you are using KDE, go to System Settings -> Bluetooth -> Configure... for a GUI-based way to turn Bluetooth on, then < to return to the previous window and select Add new device... to start the pairing process.
If you want to use command-line, the modern command to use is probably bluetoothctl. The old hcitool and gatttool commands don't seem to be available on your system.

I've tried all of the following but It doesn't work, I don't even get the option to configure.

Does your laptop actually have a Bluetooth radio chip? If you run the lsusb command, does it include anything that looks like a Bluetooth radio device? Please edit your question to add that output line to it. Depending on the exact type of the device, it might need a specific firmware package before it can work.
